# Link to file, which does not exists php

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink

Please help me to understand how not to overcomplicate my site.
For example I have files:

**index.php**

**other.php**
etc...

these files have such code

```
include '../dir/index.php';
include '../dir/other.php';
```

etc.

How to have url like "site.com/news.php" without having actual file news.php, because only one thing it does is including code?

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but why would you want to include a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: If you're using Apache, and I understand your question correctly, you're probably after [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: I mean that I do not have to create a file, but when people type site.com/news.php they actually will not have 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your Apache to send all request to you main PHP script. You can do that via different ways. The "regular" way would be to use a .htaccess file and some mod_rewrite settings. Then within your main script you have to handle the problem of not finding the file which was requested. But be careful you can create a lot of security sink holes. For example if you just parse the request parameters and without sanitizing include a file.

For that you should just look at some modern PHP frameworks like Symfony, Laravel and others. There this kind of stuff is already handle quite well.